# How to run query against JSON extract data in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following Clickhouse table:

```
id, custom, otherfield1, otherfield2.
```

In the custom, we put a JSON inside of it that looks like

```
{"activityId": 1234, "someJsonField": "blah"}
```

so now I want to query 10 rows where the activityId field is 1234. How do I go about doing this?

```
SELECT 
    custom,
    JSONExtractString(custom, 'activityId') AS ActivityId
FROM muh_table
where ActivityId = "1234"
limit 1
```

But then I get error, basically saying the column doesn't exist. What's the correct syntax in getting this SQL written out?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to share some more details. This worked fine for me:

```
create or replace table zhen (
    id UInt32,
    custom String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY id;

INSERT INTO zhen VALUES 
    (1, '{"activityId": 1234, "someJsonField": "blah1"}'),
    (2, '{"activityId": 1234, "someJsonField": "blah2"}'),
    (3, '{"activityId": 5678, "someJsonField": "blah3"}');

SELECT 
    id,
    JSONExtractString(custom, 'activityId') AS ActivityId
FROM zhen
WHERE ActivityId = '1234';
```

Response is:

```
┌─id─┬─ActivityId─┐
│  1 │ 1234       │
│  2 │ 1234       │
└────┴────────────┘
```